# Console Application with task scheduler

Tags: windows, console-application

I have created a console and I want to run it every 1-minute nonstop
I try to put in a scheduler task but I think that my configuration is done badly can someone help, please?
I want to finish this task 
thank

Comment: Why not just leave it running and use an internal timer? If this is just about manually scheduling a task its off-topic here.

Comment: This might be better as a service (with a one minute sleep/trigger) if it needs to run all the time.

Comment: @Alexk can give an example with the timer please

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can follow the tutorial here [How to Create a Automated Task that Runs at a Set Time in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html)

The steps outlined are as follows:

1. Open up `Task Scheduler` by either typing "task" into the `Start Menu` search bar, or by opening `All Programs` -> `Accesories` > `System Tools`.

[image]

2. Select '`Create Basic Task`' from the right hand pane and the '`Create Basic Task`' Wizard will open.

[image]

3. With the Wizard open, type a '`Name`' and '`Description`' for your new task and click Next.
   NOTE: The `Next` button will only be accessible once a '`Name`' has been entered.

[image]

4. Select the event/task to run `DAILY` and click `Next`.

[image]

5. Select the time as 00:00 and date at which you wish the first task to start (each task afterward will run based on your selection in step 4) then click Next.

[image]

6. Choose the action you with the task to execute from the list then click `Next`. 
   NOTE: For your query, select '`Start a program`'.

[image]

7. Click '`Browse`' and navigate to the executable (exe) file of the console app you wish to run then click `Next`. You can choose to ignore 'Add arguments' and 'Start in'.

[image]

8. Review the task and make sure that you've set all your required information correctly. If satisfied click `Finish`.

[image]

9. Click the `Advanced` button on the `Schedule` tab. There is a checkbox for `Repeat` task. The default is every 10 minutes. You can change that to 1 minute.

The key here is to find the advanced properties. If you are using the XP wizard, it will only offer you to launch the advanced dialog once you created the task.