# Run a task at midnight. Task Scheduler

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on an website using asp.net. The site needs to import data from a file and store it into a database. Right now I have a button that does the job for me. But now I need to create a scheduled task that will do the import at midnight every night. I'm guessing task scheduler is the way to do it but I have no idea how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to accomplish this task with an app running under the task scheduler being one of them.  The simplest would be to create a console application that accomplishes the same thing as what your button click does and then run that application within a scheduled task.   Here is another SO question that does a great job of outlining how to run a console app under a scheduled task.

[Console Application with task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432980/console-application-with-task-scheduler)