# How to update a SharePoint Online list if a new record is inserted in the database?

Tags: c#, mysql, rest, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a MySQL database that holds personal information. Whenever a new employee gets hired he/she fills out some personal information and that data gets stored in a table.

After some research (and since I don't have access to the other systems -only the database) the plan is to build a C# console app that retrieves the data and check it against the SharePoint list. I want to update the list (create a new item) if a new record is in the database that does not exist in the SharePoint list from before.

Note that if the SharePoint list contains more columns, then the table with additional manual information.

I have posted the connection code against the database and how I retrieve the data.

*How can I check if the item exists in the SharePoint list? Would anybody be able to provide an answer that includes code for creating and inserting the new item?* I have two columns (in both the database and SP list) that could work as a primary key.

There is a REST API that supports CRUD so I guess this should be a no-brainer.

SharePoint list:
[image: SharePoint list]

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

public class DbConnection
{
    private String databaseName;
    private String serverAddress;
    private String pwd;
    private String userName;
    private Boolean connected;
    private MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;

    public DbConnection(String databaseName, String serverAddress, String pwd, String userName)
    {
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
        this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.userName = userName;
        connected = false;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        if (connected == true)
        {
            Console.Write("There is already a connection");
        }
        else
        {
            connected = false;
            String connectionString = "server=" + serverAddress + ";" + "database=" + databaseName + ";" + "uid=" + userName + ";" + "pwd=" + pwd + ";";
            Console.WriteLine(connectionString);

            try
            {
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                conn.Open();
                Console.Write("Connection was succesfull");
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public Boolean IsConnected()
    {
        return connected;
    }

    public MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return conn;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        conn.Close();
        connected = false;
    }
}
```

Then I retrieve the data like so:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace daily_CC_SP_update
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            DbConnection mySQLConn = new DbConnection(dbName, serverAddress, pwd, userName);
            mySQLConn.Connect();

            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_CC_SP";
            MySqlCommand sqlCom = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, mySQLConn.getConnection());
            MySqlDataReader reader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();

            Console.WriteLine("Following output from DB");
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
            }

            //Keep the console alive until enter is pressed, for debugging
            Console.Read();
            mySQLConn.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

I will create a view in the database to retrieve the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the items["LockUpColumn"] not to a string but a lockup field

Answer (score 1):

First just to clarify :).. You are using SharePoint on-prem right? So we can use Farm solutions.
If yes then I would resolve this case with the fallowing solution. 
I would develop an SPJob (SharePoint Timer job). It may only be included in Farm solution. Basically it looks like this:

1. create Farm project in solution
2. add class that inherits from SPJobDefinition and put Your logic in Execute method which You need to override (in this method create a standard SQL connection and Query this table from mySQL db then compare with Your SPList and do the work :) ) (also maybe here a good approach would be to store some credentials for this connection string in some SPList on some config site or somewhere... not to hardcode it ;)) 
   For e.g.

```
public class CustomJob : SPJobDefinition
{
    public CustomJob() : base() { }
    public CustomJob(string jobName, SPService service) : base(jobName, service, null, SPJobLockType.None)
    {
        this.Title = jobName;
    }
    public CustomJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webapp) : base(jobName, webapp, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
    {
        this.Title = jobName;
    }
    public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        try
        {
            // Your logic here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("CustomJob - Execute", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

3. add new feature to the solution that scope is webApplication and add event receiver to this feature
4. on feature active register Your Timer job (remember to remove it on deactive :))

```
public class Feature2EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{
    const string JobName = "CustomJob";
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                // add job
                SPWebApplication parentWebApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
                DeleteExistingJob(JobName, parentWebApp);
                CreateJob(parentWebApp);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("CustomJob-FeatureActivated", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
    public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            try
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
                {
                    // delete job
                    SPWebApplication parentWebApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
                    DeleteExistingJob(JobName, parentWebApp);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("CustomJob-FeatureDeactivating", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
    private bool CreateJob(SPWebApplication site)
    {
        bool jobCreated = false;
        try
        {
            // schedule job for once a day
            CustomJob job = new CustomJob(JobName, site);
            SPDailySchedule schedule = new SPDailySchedule();
            schedule.BeginHour = 0;
            schedule.EndHour = 1;
            job.Schedule = schedule;

            job.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return jobCreated;
        }
        return jobCreated;
    }
    public bool DeleteExistingJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication site)
    {
        bool jobDeleted = false;
        try
        {
            foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.JobDefinitions)
            {
                if (job.Name == jobName)
                {
                    job.Delete();
                    jobDeleted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return jobDeleted;
        }
        return jobDeleted;
    }
}
```

5. deploy and activate Your feature on the web app (I think the best would be to configure the job to run every day or every hour)

   - a nice article with some example how to do that all may be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh528518(v=office.14)) (I know the article is for SP 2010 but it will work the same for 2013, 2016 and probably also 2019 (with this on-prem version I don't have much exp) :)
   - another article with same solution [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/how-to-create-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013/) (this for SP 2013)

** Update **

for SharePoint Online the above solution will not work as it is a farm solution. In Online the solution is as always something 'external' :).
For sure You already have some kind of server were You store solutions for SP online (like SP apps that are provider hosted.. etc).
My approach would be to develop a simple C# console app. First in this app do a SQL connection to mySql and query the table to get the data.. then using CSOM query SharePoint List to do the compare. 
something like this

```
    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("url"))
    {
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        string query = "add some query here";
        camlQuery.ViewXml = query;
        collListItem = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(collListItem, items => items.Include( item => item["Title"], item => .... // add other columns You need here);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        if (collListItem.Count > 0)
        {
            // Your code here :)
        }
    }
```

Also be aware that You can run CSOM with credentials of different user (like some kind of admin) giving the network credentials like this:

```
NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "companydomain");
```

Also please be aware about threshold... in CSOM You can always use paginated query were You first get 5000 items after that under 5000 etc etc. until the collection is empty :).
After You run this console app manually a couple of times to be sure it is working properly, simply add this console app to task Scheduler on this server as a new task in task library. Also there You can provide trigger time like run every hour or day etc. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432980/console-application-with-task-scheduler) is a nice stack overflow post how to add this kind of task

.. I hope the answer now is better for Your environment :)

Comment: I not using SP on-premis but Online so cannot implement a farm solution. But your last sugestion is in line with what I was planing from before so meaby that is the way to go.

Comment: ... sorry for that.. I was sure from the post that it is on-prem... please see my update to the post of online approach

Comment: No problem, thx for update! I will look in to this and come back with my solution!

Answer (score 0):

So I have had a great progress with my c# program. I have a fully functional connection between MySql database and SharePoint online using MySql.Data CSOM. Can manipulate and control all lists and data inside.

However I have one problem, nut not sure if this can be solved. Little to non information I could find around this topic.

I create a new ListItem. Set all the fields to a value. But there is one column that is of type "Person". Every employee has his own site where this links to, like Lookup. When adding a value to this field the server gives me the following error:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at SPList.CreateNewItem(String userName, Int32 employeeNumber, String fullName, String firstName, String lastName, DateTime emplymentStart, DateTime employmentEnd, String department, String mobile, String address, String postcode, String postTown, String email) in C:\Users\fjs\source\repos\daily_CC_SP_update\SPList.cs:line 153
```

[SharePoint field spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTOTl.png)

Here is the code where I am creating the new Item.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

public class SPList
{
    private readonly ClientContext context;
    private readonly List list;
    private readonly ListItemCollection items;
    private readonly Web web;

    //Credentials may be needed, its commented out!
    public SPList(String siteUrl, String listName, NetworkCredential netCred)
    {
        try
        {
            //NetworkCredential _myCredentials = netCred;
            context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
            web = context.Web;
            context.Load(items);
            context.Load(list);
            context.Load(context.Web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title));
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to SharePoint successfully!");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public void CreateNewItem(String userName, int employeeNumber, String fullName, String firstName, String lastName, DateTime emplymentStart, DateTime employmentEnd, String department, String mobile, String address, String postcode, String postTown, String email)
    {
        try
        {
            ListItemCreationInformation newItemSepc = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem newItem = list.AddItem(newItemSepc);
            newItem["Title"] = userName;
            newItem["Employee_x0020_Number"] = employeeNumber;
            newItem["Full_x0020_Name"] = fullName;
            newItem["First_x0020_Name"] = firstName;
            newItem["Last_x0020_Name"] = lastName;
            newItem["_x000a_Employment_x0020_start_x0"] = emplymentStart.Date;
            newItem["Employment_x0020_end_x0020_date"] = employmentEnd.Date;
            newItem["Department"] = department;
            newItem["Mobile"] = mobile;
            newItem["Adress"] = address;
            newItem["Postcode"] = postcode;
            newItem["Post_x0020_town"] = postTown;
            newItem["Email"] = email;
            newItem["Person"] = fullName;
            newItem.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If i comment newItem["Person"] = fullName; out the code works fine. **Can this somehow be fixed? Otherwise I have to eddid the item in SharePoint and add the value :/**

*The weird field names is because SharePoint stores it this way for some reason*